# How to predict output counts in ibm qiskit

Tags: qiskit, hadamard

In the given circuit below :

```
q = QuantumRegister(2,'q')

c = ClassicalRegister(2,'c')

qc = QuantumCircuit(q,c)

qc.h(0)

qc.h(1) qc.measure([0,1],[0,1])

backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator') job = execute(qc, backend, shots=100)

counts = job.result().get_counts()
```

How to predict the number of counts?

Answer (score 0):

```
q = QuantumRegister(2,'q')
```

You have two qubits which are initialized in $|00\rangle$ state.

`qc.h(0)` & `qc.h(1)` means you are applying the Hadamard gate on both qubits.

Hence your resultant state will be
$$|00\rangle \rightarrow \frac{1}{2} (|00\rangle+|01\rangle+|10\rangle+|11\rangle)$$

So upon $Z$-measurement, you have an equal probability of getting any of the {00,01,10,11} bitstrings. Hence your counts should be approximately equal.

Therefore,

```
backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator') job = execute(qc, backend, shots=100)
```

For the 100 shots you are measuring, you should get approximately 25 shots per bitstring.

You can predict the outcome without running the code by just performing vector-matrix multiplication, i.e. multiplying your initial state vector with the matrix representation of the circuit you are running.